# How to change all the location,rotation and scale values of a keyframed camera

Tags: camera, tracking

I have this scenario : I have separated a scene from a full lenght movie and with the voodoo camera tracker I have extracted the camera movements following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtTPGFs_S7c) :

[image: 1]

and then I have imported them into blender :

[image: 2]

right now everything is ok. But I want to do something different. As you can see,on the first stage of the project I've used an image sequence to track the movements of the camera of the original movie. BUT I have also recreated in 3D the original house where the camera was located :

[image: 3]

Now you can easily understand what I want to do : I want to take the camera movements that are saved in the timeline of the blender file where I used the image sequence and save them in the timeline of the blender file where I have recreated the house. The goal is to make move the fake camera in the same way as the original one.

I think also that you need to give a look at the python script that the voodoo camera tracker uses to save the camera movements in the timeline. I have attached it with the other relevant blender files.

[voodoo files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W-dre7hDo6mvr4ncu4CawKF9j9KtwwXF)

I ran the script directly inside the 3D house that I have recreated,but this is what happens :

[image: 5]

the movements have been added to a new camera placed in the wrong way.

Comment: It would probably work, if the scene you recreated, was placed more less in the same position as the plane with the movie scene in the first file. You could also try to append all the objects from your recreated scene into the scene with voodoo tracked camera movement and see if it fits.

Comment: I'm looking for the way to change the location,rotation and scale of all the keyframes of the broken camera...

Comment: Share the .blend files. Maybe then we'll figure out something